# Ubuntu Installing on USB Stick

Tags: ubuntu, installation

I want to install Ubuntu from a USB Stick but would like to use the same Stick as a medium Ubuntu should be installed on. Is this possible?

Comment: This would be *a lot* easier with a second usb drive.  do you have a spare 2GB usb drive?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if you have enough ram (2G?) just use the `toram` [boot option](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BootOptions#Changing_the_CD_Boot_Option_Configuration_Line)  to copy everything to ram, then you can umount or remove or do whatever you want with the boot device (USB).

Doing a regular install to a USB might not provide the results you're expecting though, I tried it once and it took a very very long time, rebooted twice, then crashed spectacularly (the filesystem went down in flames). Or maybe you'll have better luck. You might consider just adding persistence to your USB instead ([askubuntu Q](https://askubuntu.com/questions/772744/how-to-make-a-live-usb-persistent) or [UbuntuWiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/LiveUsbPendrivePersistent))

Answer (score 0):

Create a [USB drive with Ubuntu Live with *persistent storage*](https://technologyinsiders.wordpress.com/2016/12/09/how-to-create-a-live-ubuntu-usb-drive-with-persistent-storage/).

- Such a device can be used on its own, with or without access to an internal SSD or HDD.
- You can install packages, store data or otherwise use it as a normal OS.
- You can use it to install Ubuntu on a PC.

`Pro:` This is a complete operating system on a stick that you can use on any PC that allows you to mount the USB drive.

`Cons:` Flash USB drives are abysmally slow compared to to SSD or even HDD. If you plan to use this often, invest in a portable SSD -- a [128 GB drive](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0776PRPL2) can be found for less than US$45.

Also, even with a high-speed SSD, the media must find drivers for the PC on which it's mounted, so initial boot times will be long. While keeping it on one machine, use suspend (sleep) rather than rebooting.